# How to wrap a function with andThen or similar in Java functional interface

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-interface, function-composition

I have some repetitive code:

```java
router.post("/fleets/:fleetid/vehicles/:boxid/ping").handler(ctx -> pingBox(pingBoxTimer, oemUrl, ctx));
router.post("/fleets/:fleetid/vehicles/:boxid/wakeup").handler(ctx -> wakeUp(wakeupTimer, oemUrl, ctx));
router.post("/fleets/:fleetid/vehicles/:boxid/passthrough").handler(ctx -> passthrough(passthroughTimer, oemUrl, ctx));
router.post("/fleets/:fleetid/vehicles/:boxid/expert").handler(ctx -> passthrough(passthroughTimer, oemUrl, ctx));
router.post("/fleets/:fleetid/vehicles/:boxid/door").handler(ctx -> door(doorTimer, oemUrl, ctx));
```

In the handler of these methods, I:

1. Start a timer
2. Do some stuff
3. Stop the timer

E.g.:

```java
private void pingBox(Timer timer, String someArgs, RoutingContext ctx) {
    log.debug("ping request");
    
    Timer.Context timerCtx = timer.time();
    ctx.put("timer", timerCtx);

    ctx.response().headers().add("content-type", "text/plain");
    ctx.response().end("pong");

    timerCtx.stop();
}
```

How can I wrap the handler to avoid repeating code?

I've tried the following so far:

```java
private void handleWithTimer(Timer timer, String url, RoutingContext ctx, BiConsumer<String, RoutingContext> handler){

    log.debug("saving timer");
    Timer.Context timerCtx = timer.time();
    ctx.put("timer", timerCtx);

    handler.accept(url, ctx);

    timerCtx.stop();
}
```

but the result is not very readable:

```java
.. .handler(ctx -> handleWithTimer(pingBoxTimer, oemUrl, ctx, (s, c) -> pingBox(oemUrl, ctx)));
```

There must be a more concise way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your wrapping function more readable like this:

```
.handler(ctx -> handleWithTimer(pingBoxTimer, oemUrl, ctx, this::pingBox));
```

(of course only after adjusting your input parameters of pingBox, which it seems like you already did)